# Apply one click event handler to multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent, children

I'm trying to get my javascript to pop up a message under for each comment when its clicked.

I have 3 comment boxes, each has 1 "popup" button under it, and when the "popup" is clicked, it would alert a message ("Ouyeah!")

Only clicking the first "popup" link on the top alerts the message "Ouyeah!", and the message is alerted 3 times. Clicking on other 2 "popup" links has no action.

Code:

```
<div class="media">
<div class="media-body">
<p align="right">
<span><a href='javascript:;' id="reply_open">popup</a></span>
<div class="reply_form_div" STYLE="display:none;"></div>
</p>
</div>

<div class="media">
<div class="media-body">
<p align="right">
<span><a href='javascript:;' id="reply_open">popup</a></span>
<div class="reply_form_div" STYLE="display:none;"></div>
</p>
</div>

<div class="media">
<div class="media-body">
<p align="right">
<span><a href='javascript:;' id="reply_open">popup</a></span>
<div class="reply_form_div" STYLE="display:none;"></div>
</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#reply_open").parent().parent().parent().parent().children(".media-body").children("p").children("span").children("#reply_open").click(function(){
alert ("Ouyeah!");
</script>
```

Only clicking the first "popup" link on the top alerts the message "Ouyeah!", and the message is alerted 3 times. Clicking on other 2 "popup" links has no action.

How to fix this? Many thanks,

Comment: First off, element `id`s must be unique across a page. Change that and see where it gets you.

Comment: Oh god, please dont use `.parent()` x5 when locating an element. Use `.closest` -- else next time you change your DOM this function will potentially break. (Depending on the size of your app, it will also be a giant pain to locate / fix)

Comment: Thanks Jason P. Do you suggest that I use a class instead?

Comment: Your HTML looks broken too - where is a close `div` for 'div class="media"'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your HTML is incorrect in a few ways:

- Your `id's` must be unique
- You didn't close your `.media` div tags.
- You're using JavaScript for a empty href

Try this instead:

```
<div class="media">
    <div class="media-body">
        <p align="right">
            <span><a href='./'>popup</a></span>
            <div class="reply_form_div" STYLE="display:none;"></div>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="media">
    <div class="media-body">
        <p align="right">
            <span><a href='./'>popup</a></span>
            <div class="reply_form_div" STYLE="display:none;"></div>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="media">
    <div class="media-body">
        <p align="right">
            <span><a href='./'>popup</a></span>
            <div class="reply_form_div" STYLE="display:none;"></div>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I removed the `id`'s altogether, they're not necessary. The `.media` divs are properly closed, and the JavaScript was removed from the hrefs.

Then, instead of searching through the DOM like you're doing with chained `.parent()` calls, try this js:

```
<script>
    $('.media .media-body a').click(function(){
        alert("Ouyeah!");
    });
</script>
```

This adds a event handler to each `a`, that should alert the desired text.

**[Working example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/HV52r/)**

Comment: Ah great! Thanks so much. So I see "a" directly follows .media-body. But I also have <p> <span> level between media and them. Why not use the following? Thanks! <script>
    $('.media .media-body p span a').click(function(){
        alert("Ouyeah!");
    });
</script>

Comment: Well, you could also write: $('html > body div.media > div.media-body > p[align=right] > span(not:[doorbell=five]) > a[href=./]'), but chances are you don't gain any benefit from being so specific.

Comment: `'.media .media-body a'` means: Find me a `a` that is somewhere in a element with class `media-body`, that is somewhere in a element with class `media`. It doesn't matter if there's some more nesting between those elements. We could leave out the `.media` or `.media-body`. Also, please consider accepting this as your answer, if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have duplicate IDs.

Using `id="reply_open"` thrice (more than once!) is wrong and makes your HTML invalid.

JSFIDDLE DEMO -> http://jsfiddle.net/LC9gg/4/

This may be what you want. Make the IDs as classes & write the below code.

```
$(".reply_open").click(function () {
    alert("Ouyeah!");
});
```

Comment: En I see. How would you suggest that I change this to get to the effect I want?

Comment: Use classes instead or unique IDs. Also, don't use `parent().parent()`, use `.closest`.

Comment: While the suggestion is correct, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: So now I'm using this: Is that right? <script type="text/javascript">
$(".reply_open").closest(".reply_open").click(function(){
alert ("Ouyeah!");
</script>

Comment: @user3192948 - I updated my answer, that may be what you wanted.

Comment: This still doesn't fix the broken html structure. Also, `<a href="#"></a>` is commonly used to navigate the user to the top of the page. I doubt that's desired behavior.

Comment: The `<div class="media">` divs aren't closed.

Comment: ... All 3 of them. Take a look at the DOM structure in a proper text editor / IDE.